# Gradient Descent global minimum?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

For the gradient descent algorithm which minimizes the average squared error, the algorithm finds coefficients to a linear predictor. The algorithm I am referring to is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eikJboPQDT0). These coefficients that the algorithm finds converge to the **global** minimum if the learning rate is small enough. We know there is a global minimum because the average squared error is a convex function of the weights.

What about as a function of the learning rate (aka alpha in the linked video)? Consider two methods for choosing the learning rate:

**METHOD 1**

iterate over all i in the range -15 to 2.

- for each i let learning rate be 3^i .
- run gradient descent for 20000 iterations
- measure your training error

Choose learning 3^i for the i that had the lowest training error.

**METHOD 2**

iterate over all i in the range -15 to 2.

- for each i let learning rate be 3^i .
- run gradient descent for 20000 iterations
- measure your training error
- if error is higher than previous iteration, choose the i from the previous iteration and break the loop

Is Method 2 correct in assuming that once error increase for some choice of learning rate, all learning rates that are bigger than that one will be even worse?

In method 1 we went over all values of learning rate in a range. In method 2, we said we dont need to go over all values- just until we see an increase in error.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting you,

> ...and measure the error after some fixed number of iterations and
>   when you see an increase in error...

Well, according to the video, this is how we detect the convergence, if the difference in gradient descent is <= 0.001 or some value, so there is already a bound you have set which will not allow further iteration for higher values in change of cost function.

There is only one local/global minima for the convex functions when the hypothesis is a linear predictor, so the gradient descent will naturally bring it down to that minima point.

Comment: See my edit. I see that my original question was not clear